# How injecting a array in my view with laravel 5 using a facade and the App:make method in the view

Tags: laravel-5, dependency-injection

I created a facade that works well, a using service container :

#### My class:

```php
namespace App\Classes;

class Administration {
    public function message_success()
    {
        $message = "success";
        return $message;
    }
}
```

#### My view:

```php
{{ App::make('administration')->message_success() }}
```

Resultat: Ok

But when I want to work with a array, I can not retrieve a value in my view with `App::make`.

#### My class:

```php
namespace App\Classes;
class Administration {
    public function message_test($message, array $type = array())
    {
        $type = ['message1' => 'valeur1', 'message2' => 'valeur2'];
        return $message;
    }
}
```

How to build the syntax in my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view

```php
{{ App::make('administration')->message_test($message) }}
```

In your class

```php
namespace App\Classes;
class Administration {
    public function message_test($message)
    {
        $type = ['message1' => 'valeur1', 'message2' => 'valeur2'];
        return $type[$message];
    }
}
```

Instead of

```php
namespace App\Classes;
class Administration {
    public function message_test($message, array $type = array())
    {
        $type = ['message1' => 'valeur1', 'message2' => 'valeur2'];
        return $message;
    }
}
```

As you can see I dropped the `$type` parameter, you are defining/overwriting it within your method. Also, to return the value of `message1` you need to access `$type` with the key being `message1`.

Comment: It works ! Great. In my view I have the following syntax: `{{ App::make('administration')->message_test('message2') }}` this returns valeur2. Thank. (The aim will still be to manage since my controller).